# Как вывести все выбранные файлы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть поле `<input type="file" />`. Когда я выбираю несколько файлов, хочу получить этот массив и вывести ниже списком пути файлов.

Есть такой код:

```
$('.add_photo_input').on('change', function() {
    var value = $('form input[type=file]').val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Я получаю значение только последнего выбранного файла, а мне надо всех выбранных: могу выбрать и три файла, и нужно получить пути всех трёх файлов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имена всех выбранных файлов можно получить с помощью поля `files` (тип [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)) у `<input type="file" />`, которое представляет собой список из [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File):

```js
$('form input[type=file]').on('change', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.files[i].name);
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="file" multiple />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Статья на MDN про работу с файлами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).